# Specifying '!important' for CSS 'opacity'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

I am including a 3rd-party component library in my project, therefore I cannot control the CSS defined within it. According to this page (https://cssinjs.org/jss-syntax/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.22), it is possible to specify the `!important` attribute using this approach:

```
const styles = {
    button: {
        color: [['red'], '!important'],
        margin: [[5, 10], '!important']
    }
}
```

This is a small snippet of the code I am using, but it demonstrates the error:

```
const styles = (theme: Theme) => {
    return createStyles({
        '@global': {
            '.tree-node-selected': {
                opacity: [1, '!important'],
            },
        },
    })
}
```

The error is:

```
Type '{ '.tree-node-selected': { opacity: ReactText[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties | (() => CSSProperties)'.
  Type '{ '.tree-node-selected': { opacity: ReactText[]; }; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
    Property ''.tree-node-selected'' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type '{ opacity: ReactText[]; }' is not assignable to type 'string | number | CSSProperties | undefined'.
        Type '{ opacity: ReactText[]; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
          Types of property 'opacity' are incompatible.
            Type 'ReactText[]' is not assignable to type 'number | "-moz-initial" | "inherit" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset" | undefined'.
              Type 'ReactText[]' is not assignable to type '"unset"'.ts(2322)
```

If I change to code to: `opacity: '1 !important'`, the error then becomes:

```
Type '{ '.tree-node-selected': { opacity: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties | (() => CSSProperties)'.
  Type '{ '.tree-node-selected': { opacity: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
    Property ''.tree-node-selected'' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type '{ opacity: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string | number | CSSProperties | undefined'.
        Type '{ opacity: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
          Types of property 'opacity' are incompatible.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | "-moz-initial" | "inherit" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset" | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

I have been able to get the effect I want by including a `<style>` tag within the `render()`, such as:

```
<style>{`.tree-node-selected {opacity: 1 !important}`}</style>
```

Does anyone have any other/better recommendations for how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing some square brackets around your opacity:

```
const styles = (theme: Theme) => {
    return createStyles({
        '@global': {
            '.tree-node-selected': {
                opacity: [[1], '!important'],
            },
        },
    })
}
```